# Whether the return value of a function modified by python decorator can only be Nonetype

Tags: python, decorator, nonetype

I wrote a decorator that gets the runtime of the program, but the function return value becomes Nonetype.

```
def gettime(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        t1 = time.time()
        func(*args, **kw)
        t2 = time.time()
        t = (t2-t1)*1000
        print("%s run time is: %.5f ms"%(func.__name__, t))

    return wrapper
```

If I don't use the decorator, the return value is correct.

```
A = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 100))
B = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 100))
def contrast(a, b):
    res = np.sum(np.equal(a, b))/(A.size)
    return res

res = contrast(A, B)
print("The correct rate is: %f"%res)
```

The result is:`The correct rate is: 0.012400`

And if i use the decorator:

```
@gettime
def contrast(a, b):
    res = np.sum(np.equal(a, b))/len(a)
    return res

res = contrast(A, B)
print("The correct rate is: %f"%res)
```

There will report a error:

```
contrast run time is: 0.00000 ms
```

`TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType`

Of course, if I remove the `print` statement, I can get the correct running time, but the `res` accepts the Nonetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the wrapper *replaces* the function decorated, it also needs to pass on the return value:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kw):
    t1 = time.time()
    ret = func(*args, **kw)  # save it here
    t2 = time.time()
    t = (t2-t1)*1000
    print("%s run time is: %.5f ms"%(func.__name__, t))
    return ret  # return it here
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can  do:

```
def gettime(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        t1 = time.time()
        func(*args, **kw)
        t2 = time.time()
        t = (t2-t1)*1000
        print("%s run time is: %.5f ms"%(func.__name__, t))
        print("The correct rate is: %f"%func(*args,**kw))
    return wrapper


@gettime
def contrast(a, b):
    res = np.sum(np.equal(a, b))/a.size
    return res
contrast(A,B)
```